Understanding downvotes and writing a good question
I would like to understand why my question was downvoted
In the end I did end up solving my own problem and posted the answer which I believe would be valuable to someone else finding themselves in the same situation.
My question here is really how can/could I improve the question, so I can write better questions in the future.
EF Core: "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types" when verifying database connection

1 downvote.... Don't worry about it.

@Paulie_D You have to worry about it because it prevents you from asking questions in the future

:shrug: i don't think there's anything more you needed to do, we can't really explain why one random person decided it wasn't useful. The very nature of your question lacked details, not because you didn't provide them but because there weren't any to provide. Some questions can just be inherently not useful.

No, it doesn't prevent you at all.

Deleted questions, score <= 0, contributing to the question ban: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

@Paulie_D Downvotes do in fact result in question bans (as has, in fact, happened here).  Of course, a single downvote on a single question alone, doesn't, but in aggregate...

Ah, there was no intimation of a ban being in force :)

@JoséphFlames - If you never ask a question then delete the question you don’t have to worry about a question ban unless you make a pattern of asking questions that are downvoted more than once. Your question asking history is poor because of those deleted questions.

On writing a good question, give this a read.

Note, I deleted your answer which does not really answer the question because you don't know what actually happened and the answer is mere observation.  It can hardly help anyone else. The question is closed as not reproducible. I am leaving to you to delete it if you want as there is not much you can improve there.

The question and subject are out of my areas of expertise, but at least a few issues come to mind:

The answer that you yourself have posted suggests that the question itself is not answerable based on the information that you've posted. This suggests that both question and answer are not going to make a positive contribution to the site.
You received one, and only one downvote when you posted this meta question. This means that a single site member decided to downvote the question. I'm not sure why this would deserve a meta post of its own. How can anyone guess why a single user would downvote a question. More importantly, why should any of us (or you) care why a single user downvoted a question.
Beware of the meta effect where your highlighting your own main site contribution on meta will bring additional attention to this contribution. This can augment voting on a question or answer or both, sometimes in a positive direction, but often in a negative one. This can easily change a single downvote into many, if many deem that the Q or A deserve this.



Some Tags are probably missing in the Question, I would think, where only c# is included, => mariadb + entity-framework-core...(?). + Missing punctuation in several sentences, especially the final dot (same also in this current Question on 'Meta')...

